# Strange Boss around Level 110

Tags: clicker-heroes

In Clicker Heroes I normally encounter some strange creeper mostly around the level 110 . Does anyone of you know if there is something special about him or if it's just a picture of someone? Maybe the developer itself?

[image: Strange Boss at Level 110]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've come across the "secret" Kappa boss.  From the [wiki](http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Easter_Eggs) (go down to the Miscellaneous section):

> Secret "Kappa" Boss: When reaching a boss level, there is a chance
>   that instead of spawning the normal boss for that level, it will spawn
>   this "Kappa" boss instead. It is a Turtloid Warlock enemy with the
>   twitch.tv "Kappa" emote on its face.

There's a little more info [here](http://lazythunk.com/kappa/) about Kappa.

Also important to note is that this boss doesn't give any extra benefit or reward.  I'm not sure if it will ever spawn as a primal boss.

Comment: This boss can actually spawn as primal! It happened to me.